# SQL INSERT - Invalid column name

Tags: c#, sql, insert

As some of you may of seen from my previous post I'm new to using C# to create websites (Although I have a fair bit of experience using it for Windows Forms apps). The powers that be are tempting me away from PHP but I keep failing at what I consider the basics.

Anyway, this is my issue. I am trying to create a simple entry into a SQL database. I know my connection to the DB is fine as I can reel off SELECT queries all day long but I'm having trouble with using Insert.

Heres my code:

```
string filename = "abc123.jpg";
SqlConnection link = new SqlConnection(//you dont need to see my data here ;));
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename VALUES ("+filename+")";
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(sqlcode,link);
link.open();
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This results in "Invalid column name abc123.jpg" returned from the try/catch.

Any help would be appreciated. (I wish they would let me do this in PHP lol!)

Thanks,

Tripbrock

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis after the column name and the value represents a string and as such must be enclosed in quotes:

```
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) " + 
                 "VALUES ('"+filename+"')";
```

However, the correct way would be to use a parameterized query:

```
string filename = "abc123.jpg";
SqlConnection link = new SqlConnection(/*you dont need to see my data here ;)*/);
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES (@filename)";
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(sqlcode,link);
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", filename);
link.open();
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Missing ''! I need shooting. Thanks! Also, thanks again for the heads up on using Params.

Answer (score 2):

your SQL is bad formatted. Try this :

```
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES ('"+filename+"')";
```

Where upload_filename is a name of the column

Comment: +1 for the missing single quotes around filename. Though I'd argue it would be better to parameterise the SQL instead

Answer (score 1):

Really you should be parameterising your queries - this reduces the risk of injection attacks:

```
string filename = "abc123.jpg";
using( SqlConnection link = new SqlConnection(/*...*/;)) )
{
    // sql statement with parameter
    string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES (@filename)";
    using( SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(sqlcode,link) )
    {
        // add filename parameter
        sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("filename", filename);
        link.open();
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also note the `using` statements - these make sure that the connection and command objects are disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing a bracket:

```
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename VALUES ("+filename+")";
```

Should be

```
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES ('"+filename+"')";
```

Also, to avoid SQL injection attacks you can use the SQLCommand objects like so.

```
using (SQLCommand oSQLCommand = new SQLCommand("INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES ( @FileName )")
{
oSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);

oSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You are also missing single quotes around the string value. Tsk tsk.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES ('"+filename+"')";
```

You were missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: And you are missing single quotes around the string value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is a typo but the line should be:

`string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES ('"+filename+"')";`

Notice the `)` after `upload_filename`.

Also also added the single quotes around the filename.

But you probably want to use a parameterized query:

`string sqlcode = "INSERT INTO file_uploads (upload_filename) VALUES (@filename)";`

Then use `command.Parameters` to add the actual value.